# modular automorphism group of faithful weight

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

[image]

Theorem 2.11 is from Takeski's book (Vol 2. Chapter VIII, Section 2).

It mentions that we can get $\sigma^{\psi}_t(x)=(he_n)^{it}\sigma^{\varphi}_t(x)(he_n)^{-it}$ by Lemma 2.10.
I have a question: $x\in M_{e_n}$, it is also in $M$, by Lemma 2.10, we have $\sigma^{\psi}_t(x)=(he_n)^{it}\sigma^{\varphi}_t(x)(he_n)^{-it}$$\sigma^{\psi}_t(x)=(h)^{it}\sigma^{\varphi}_t(x)(h)^{-it}$. Why should we replace $h$ by $he_n$.

Another question: how to derive $(he_n)^{it}=(h)^{it}$?

In the proof of Theorem of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $h$ is affiliated with $\mathcal M_\varphi$ implies that $he_n\in \mathcal M_\varphi$. So, for $x\in e_n\mathcal M e_n$
\begin{align}
\sigma_t^\psi(x)
&=
(he_n)^{it}\sigma_t^\varphi(x)(he_n)^{it}=h^{it}e_n\sigma_t^\varphi(x)e_nh^{it}\\[0,3cm]
&=h^{it}\sigma_t^\varphi(e_n)\sigma_t^\varphi(x)\varphi(e_n)h^{it}=h^{it}\sigma_t^\varphi(e_nxe_n)h^{it}\\[0.3cm]
&=h^{it}\sigma_t^\varphi(x)h^{it}.
\end{align}
The first equality is due to Lemma 2.10 applied to $he_n\in e_n\mathcal Me_n$.

Comment: Why $(he_n)^{it}=(h)^{it}e_n$?

Comment: Functional calculus. It is trivial to check that $(f\,1_E)^{it}=f^{it}\,1_E$.

Comment: I know the fact :Let $h=u|h|$ be the polar decomposition of $h$. Then $h$ is affiliated with $M_{\varphi}$ iff $u$ and the spectral projection of $|h|$ are in $M_{\varphi}$ . We have $e_n\in M_{\varphi}$. But why $he_n\in M_{\varphi}$?

Comment: Because $he_n$ is a limit of linear combinations of spectral projections of $h$.

Comment: I am still confused about the calculation of the modular automorphism groups. I the above proof, the restriction of $\varphi$ to $M_{e_n}$ is a faithful weight on $M_{e_n}$  whose modular automorphism group is the restriction of $\{\sigma_t^{\varphi}\}$ to $M_{e_n}$. How to prove the above statement?

Comment: When you have a corner $pMp$, with the same faithful $\varphi$, the GNS representation is simply the original GNS restricted to a subspace; the operators $S$ and $F$ are the restrictions of the original $S$ and $F$ to that subspace. So the elements that form the modular group are simply the restrictions of those from the full algebra. And, what do you mean by $\sigma$-weakly continuous?

Comment: The author want to prove $ \sigma^{\psi}_t(x)=(h)^{it}\sigma^{\varphi}_t(x)(h)^{-it}$ for all $x\in M$. According to the proof in the screenshot, we have $\sigma^{\psi}_t(x)=(h)^{it}\sigma^{\varphi}_t(x)(h)^{-it}$ for all $x\in \cup e_n Me_n$. If the  map $ \sigma^{\psi}_t:M \rightarrow M$ is not $\sigma$-weakly continuous, how to get the conclusion?

Comment: You mean for fixed $t$? It's unitary conjugation.

Comment: We have $\sigma^{\psi}_t(x)=(h)^{it}\sigma^{\varphi}_t(x)(h)^{-it}$ for all $x\in \cup e_n Me_n$. How to conclude $\sigma^{\psi}_t(x)=(h)^{it}\sigma^{\varphi}_t(x)(h)^{-it}$ for all $x\in M$? Should we use the fact that $\cup e_n Me_n$ is weakly dense in $M$?

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: It's unitary conjugation.

Comment: I still don't under how to understand  how to prove $\sigma^{\psi}_t(x)=(h)^{it}\sigma^{\varphi}_t(x)(h)^{-it}$ by using the fact that $\cup e_n Me_n$ is $\sigma$-weakly dense in $M$.

Comment: Not sure what you want. You have an equality of continuous functions on a dense set; then the functions are equal.

Comment: You mention that the functions  are continuous. I wonder in which topology the functions are continuous?

Comment: Norm, wot, sot, sot$^*$, $\sigma$-wot, $\sigma$-sot, $\sigma$-sot$^*$. And others. It is really hard to come up with a topology in which unitary conjugation is not continuous. I wouldn't even know where to start looking.